# jQuery to get Current Date Time in "F j, Y G:i:s" form

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I am trying to get/convert **current date time** in (e.g.) `October 18, 2015 2:30:24` form. I am interested in this specific format, because it's the one I am using in my PHP part as -

```
$start_time = time();
echo date("F j, Y G:i:s", $start_time );
```

I tried jQuery

```
new Date($.now());
```

but, it's returning as - `Sun Oct 18 2015 02:35:29 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)`
How to convert this or direct get in `F j, Y G:i:s` format?

Comment: I'd suggest to get the date from server, the date on client side may differ from server

Comment: @Tushar but how do I receive current date time in jQuery(.js file)  from server? I mean I am displaying it through PHP in .php file, but how to `echo` in .js?

Comment: @Tushar, Thanks. Let me try.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FDate